# Adding multiple markers to react google maps while using geocoder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

What I'm trying to do is send in an array of addresses to a component, use google's geocoder to convert those addresses into lat / long coordinates, and then plat those places on a google map with markers using the google maps api react wrapper. I followed this tutorial pretty closely (https://dev.to/jessicabetts/how-to-use-google-maps-api-and-react-js-26c2) with the biggest difference being that I worked in geocoder. Because geocoder is asynchronous, I can't get the map to re-render with the newly converted coordinates after the promise is resolved. Below is the code I have right now:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react';

const mapStyles = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '300px'
};

let geocoder;
let addressData = [{location: "146 Pierrepont St, Brooklyn, NY, USA"}, {location: "153 Remsen St, Brooklyn, NY, USA"}];

export class MapContainer extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.onMarkerClick = this.onMarkerClick.bind(this);
    this.displayMarkers = this.displayMarkers.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        lat: 40.6946768,
        lng: -73.99161700000002,
        showingInfoWindow: false,
        activeMarker: {},
        selectedPlace: {},
        places: [],
        stores: [{latitude: 47.49855629475769, longitude: -122.14184416996333},
          {latitude: 47.359423, longitude: -122.021071},
          {latitude: 47.2052192687988, longitude: -121.988426208496},
          {latitude: 47.6307081, longitude: -122.1434325},
          {latitude: 47.3084488, longitude: -122.2140121},
          {latitude: 47.5524695, longitude: -122.0425407}]
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.plotPoints()
  }

  plotPoints () {
    let locations = this.getPoints(geocoder)
    let places = new Array()

    Promise.all(locations)
      .then(function(returnVals) {
        returnVals.forEach(function(latLng) {
          let place = {latitude: latLng[0], longitude: latLng[1]}
          places.push(place)
        })
      })
    this.setState (() => {
      return {
          places: places
      }
    });
  }

  getPoints(geocoder) {
    let locationData = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < addressData.length; i++) {
      locationData.push(this.findLatLang(addressData[i].location, geocoder))
    }
    return locationData // array of promises
  }

  findLatLang(address, geocoder) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
      }, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          console.log(results);
          resolve([results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()]);
        } else {
          reject(new Error('Couldnt\'t find the location ' + address));
        }
      })
    })
  }

  displayMarkers (stores) {
    return stores.map((place, index) => {
      return <Marker key={index} id={index} position={{
       lat: place.latitude,
       lng: place.longitude
     }}
     onClick={() => console.log("You clicked me!")} />
    })
  }

  onMarkerClick (props, marker, e) {
    this.setState({
      selectedPlace: props,
      activeMarker: marker,
      showingInfoWindow: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    geocoder = new this.props.google.maps.Geocoder();
    return (
      <div className="container place-map">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <Map
              google={this.props.google}
              zoom={14}
              style={mapStyles}
              initialCenter={{
                lat: this.state.lat,
                lng: this.state.lng
              }}
              
            >
              {this.displayMarkers(this.state.stores)}
              {this.displayMarkers(this.state.places)}
              <InfoWindow
                marker={this.state.activeMarker}
                visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
              >
                <div>Your Location Here!</div>
              </InfoWindow>
            </Map>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyCOJDrZ_DXmHzbzSXv74mULU3aMu3rNrQc'
})(MapContainer);
```

The array of "stores" renders markers on the map since there are coordinates available at the initial render of the map - but the coordinates that get pushed onto the "places" array never render. If I put a log statement of the "places" into render() I can see that I am getting back valid coordinates from geocoder.

Help! Been banging my head on this for forever (as you can tell by the current sloppy state of the code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `setState` for `places` into the `Promise.all` callback.

You are calling it when the array is still empty and before the promises have resolved

```
Promise.all(locations)
  .then((returnVals) =>{
    returnVals.forEach((latLng) => {
      let place = {
        latitude: latLng[0],
        longitude: latLng[1]
      }
      places.push(place)
    })

    // places now populated
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        places: places
      }
    });

  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but its still not rendering the markers - and after doing that the place coordinates don't even show up anymore if log them to the console in render().

Comment: Ooooh ... didn't notice you are not using arrow functions. Try with update. Changes the `this` context